# ERROR 1003: Unable to find an operator for alias truck_events_subset

Tags: apache-pig, hue

I have written a pig script :

```
truck_events = LOAD '/user/data/truck_event_text_partition.csv' USING PigStorage(',')
AS (driverId:int, truckId:int, eventTime:chararray,                 
eventType:chararray, longitude:double, latitude:double,
eventKey:chararray, correlationId:long, driverName:chararray,
routeId:long,routeName:chararray,eventDate:chararray);
DESCRIBE truck_events;
truck_events_subset = LIMIT truck_events 100;
DESCRIBE truck_events_subset;
DUMP truck_events_subset;
```

But I get an error :

> ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1003: Unable to find an
>   operator for alias truck_events_subset

Comment: Check to see if the data was loaded correctly by dumping truck_events.Its possible that the load failed.Edit the questions and show sample data from your file.

Comment: how can I know if the data was loaded correctly by dumping truck_events or failed ?

Comment: if dump truck_events does not show records from the file then that means your load has failed,in that case any PIG statement after the load statement will throw an error.

Comment: When I run the load script, I get the status SUCCEEDED and when I look at the log file, I don't find any errors.

Comment: What does dump truck_events print?

Comment: No thing, and I get the error 1003.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129626/discussion-between-inquisitive-mind-and-g-saleh).

Answer (score 0):

The data in the CorrelationId field is a double precision floating point number.Change the datatype to double.

```
truck_events = LOAD '/user/data/truck_event_text_partition.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (driverId:int, truckId:int, eventTime:chararray,eventType:chararray, longitude:double, latitude:double,eventKey:chararray, correlationId:double, driverName:chararray,routeId:long,routeName:chararray,eventDate:chararray);
```